# Как изменить CSS свойства эллемента при наведении на него мыши?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Есть такой код: https://jsfiddle.net/y7cj5tmr/

```
<style>

.outer {
  padding:20px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner {
  height:100%;
  background-color: red;
}

</style>

...

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Содержимое 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Содержимое 2
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Содержимое 3
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Нужно чтобы при наведении мыши на один из трех блоков, менялись CSS свойства входящих в этот блок div'ов.

Например при наведении мыши на средний блок, у внешнего и внутреннего div'а менялись цвета background'ов.

Подскажите, как это сделать на css и javascript не меняя html код (без jQuery).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Используйте псевдокласс `:hover`

```css
.outer {
  padding:20px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner {
  height:100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.outer:hover .inner {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.outer:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Содержимое 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Содержимое 2
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Содержимое 3
    </div>
</div>
```